# Why Type Mismatch for int b=1*a=10;?

Tags: java

During my Project work I wrote following code.

```
int a=10;
int b=1*a=10;<-----
       ~~~~~~
```

I came to know `eclipse` is suggesting me to change type of b to `boolean`????.

It gives `unextected type error in cmd/Type mismatch in eclipse` **WHY**?

***According to*** me error **should** be `left hand side of assignment must be variable`.

*(Note: same thing happens for* `-,+,/` etc.)

Comment: what are you trying to do in the second line?

Comment: Hmmm, `javac` gives a somewhat more cryptic error: `error: unexpected type .... required: variable found: value`. Arrow points at the `*`. Not quite sure what to make of it... Also, when I copy-paste the code into Eclipse, I get `syntax error on token "=", <= expected`, which then changes to what you got...

Comment: @TAsk I don't know, hence why I didn't post an answer. At least based on the initial Eclipse error, it seems that the Eclipse compiler thinks you want `<=` instead of `=`, which would explain its error message. As for *why* it thinks that, I have no clue.

Comment: If it *really* bothers you, feel free to file a bug report for Eclipse. I'm somewhat skeptical it would lead to anything since the code wouldn't compile anyways, but it might be interesting to learn why that particular error is emitted instead of the one emitted by `javac`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The compiler is taking `(1*a=10)` to be an expression. It feels that you want to check whether the expression is `true` or not and store a `Boolean` value(true or false) in the variable b accordingly. It infers that for such an assignment, the data type of b should be `Boolean` and not `int`. Hence it gives a type mismatch error. Hope that makes sense :)

Answer (score 1):

Put a=10 into bracket eq

```
int b=1*(a=10);
```

Java can not resolve 1*a=10 as variable because [Operator Precedence](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html) and 1*a is expression